# Callbacks between javascript from the main page and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, backend

So, I've been trying to build my first website, the front-end seems to be all set, but i need to do some back-end stuuf that i can't wrap my head around.

I have a script that add a calendar to the home page, the calendar data is stored inside a text file. **I need to get this data from my server using node.js**, but i just didn't get how to do it.

`

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 function read_calendar(calendar_type){
     var data = fs.readFileSync('../data/meta/cal_'+calendar_type+'.txt', 'utf8');

     //then it should go to this variable in the main page script
     meta_text = data;
  }
  //this is for when we want to use another page to overwright the file with new data

function write_calendar(calendar_type,calendar_text,password){
    //here i check if the text from the input is the same as the security
     var password = fs.readFileSync('../data/meta/pass.txt', 'utf8');
  if(senha==pass){
      fs.writeFileSync('../data/meta/cal_'+calendar_type+'.txt', calendar_text);
  }else{
      //idk what to do if error, probalbly just a console.log('wrong pass or something else');
  }
}
//this is callbacks are from my main page script
read_calendar('ig1');
write_calendar('ig2','text','pass');
```

The thing is, how do i make this callbacks and get the data?

Comment: One word: AJAX. What are you using as web framework? express? (Also: just because both back and frontend use JS doesn't mean they share variables or functions. The communication is entirely based on HTTP requests just like with any other backend.)

Comment: Seems to be a misunderstanding between how client and server communicates. You need to use `fetch` on client side to certain endpoints located on your server to access information and get information back.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the synchronous function. **`readFileSync`**. To handle things in callback you use **`readFile(path, options, callbackFunction)`**. This will help you to manage your work async and don't have to wait to read or write your file. Use this kind of syntax -

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

check this - [readFile Function](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)

Comment: Changing readFileSync to readFile will not actually change anything in this case, since they'll have to wait for the passwords file before they can send the response back to the client whatever readFile version is used.